# Vue update variable and refresh in another component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have form component and in catch part I push errors tu my StatusBar component:

```
}).catch(error => {
     StatusBar.methods.handleErrors(error.response.data)
})
```

In my StatusBar component I want to show this errors like:

```
handleErrors(newErrors) {
       this.errors = [];

       if (newErrors.errors) {
          for (var i in newErrors.errors) {
              this.errors.push(newErrors.errors[i][0]);
          }
       }
}
```

I tried in view area to add:
`<div class="alert alert-danger" v-for="error in this.errors">{{ error }}</div>`

The problem is in console output I see the correct result, but in the view area is nothing updated. I tried also with `v-model` but nothing was updated.

How can I push results from loop automatically/update to alert?

Comment: Is the errors variable defined in the data segment of your component? Also, have you tried excluding `this.` from the `v-for` in the div as follows?

`<div class="alert alert-danger" v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</div>`

Comment: Yes, I definied it like `data() {
            return {
                errors: []
            }
        }`

I can use `errors` or `this.errors`, the outcome is the same, variable is empty

Comment: Try placing the following section to your component and let me know if the alert event fires.

`watch: {
    errors: function(errs) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(errs));
    }
}`

Comment: No, I did't get any alert. But in console I see as espected: `["The name field is required.", "The file field is required."]`

Comment: And the console output is as an error message or from a request?

Comment: In console I see error messages from my request, they are server side messages. But in console I can see them, there is only problem with update in "html" area...

Comment: Are those two components within the same Vue instance?

Comment: @OmariCelestine In my form component I import this component with `import StatusBar from '../../main/StatusBar';` so there is no parent/child component, is this wrong?

Comment: The general notion of Vue is that component to component communication is not directly possible. They would either have to be within the same instance or children of another component in which they would communicate via properties (using `props`) from their parent. I am not sure if there is a shortcut for this.

Comment: @OmariCelestine solved with props, thank you